# Structural Programming in Scala with Shapeless: How to use the SYB implementation correctly?

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless

I want to use the [SYB](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/) implementation in the [Shapeless library](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) to write the following generic traversal function:

```
class Data

// Perform the desired manipulation on the given data 
object manipulate extends ->((data: Data) => data)

def traverseAndManipulate[B](expr: B): B = {
  everywhere(manipulate)(expr)
}
```

Unfortunately, this code produces the following type error (using Shapeless 2.0.0-M1 and Scala 2.10.2):

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : shapeless.EverywhereAux[SYB.manipulate.type]
[error]  required: ?{def apply(x$1: ? >: B): ?}
[error] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
[error]  both method inst1 in trait PolyInst of type [A](fn: shapeless.Poly)(implicit cse: fn.ProductCase[shapeless.::[A,shapeless.HNil]])A => cse.Result
[error]  and macro method apply in object Poly of type (f: Any)shapeless.Poly
[error]  are possible conversion functions from shapeless.EverywhereAux[SYB.manipulate.type] to ?{def apply(x$1: ? >: B): ?}
[error]     everywhere(manipulate)(expr)
```

I assume, that the type parameter `B` needs to be constrained in some way, to make the implicit macros of the Shapeless library applicable, but I have no idea how.

Can such a traversal function be written using Shapeless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make an implicit witness for the everywhere combinator available in the body of your method,

```
def traverseAndManipulate[B](expr: B)
  (implicit e: Everywhere[manipulate.type, B]) = everywhere(manipulate)(expr)
```

Note that for reasons that I'm not able to fathom just at the moment, giving `traverseAndManipulate` an explicit result type of `B` causes the compiler to report a similar ambiguity. The result type is however correctly inferred as `B`. If you prefer to have an explicit result type, the following should be equivalent,

```
def traverseAndManipulate[B](expr: B)
  (implicit e: Everywhere[manipulate.type, B] { type Result = B }): B = e(expr)
```