# How to define a generic 'replace' function in Scala using structural programming with Shapeless?

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless

This is a [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726824/) on how to implement generic transformers in Scala using the SYB implementation in the [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library.

I want to define a generic "replace" function in Scala with the help of the `everywhere` combinator defined in Shapeless:

```
def genericReplace[A, B](x: A, y: A, expr: B) = {

  object replace extends ->((a: A) => if (a == x) y else a)

  def transform(implicit e: Everywhere[replace.type, B]) = e(expr)

  transform
}
```

This function should replace every occurrence of `x` with `y` in the given expression `expr`.
Unfortunately, this function does not work as I want to. Applying `genericReplace` to the value `tree`

```
sealed trait Tree[T]
case class Leaf[T](t: T) extends Tree[T]
case class Node[T](left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]

val tree: Tree[Int] = Node(Node(Leaf(1), Node(Leaf(2), Leaf(3))), Leaf(4))

val result = genericReplace(1, 100, tree)
```

does not change the given value at all.

Is there a way to make this example work? How do I use the Shapeless `everywhere` combinator correctly in my code?

Comment: You call `e(expr)` but the example linked shows `everywhere(expr)` -- is that the issue?

Comment: @Daenyth Have a look at the accepted answer from the linked question and you will understand why `e(expr)` is used in the code above.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?